# Is past simple possible in "Today I learned that you (had) released an LP"?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

> I bought the single when it was out almost 4 years ago  and since then I have always played it , still one of my faves . Today I learned that you **(had) released** an LP and but it seems to be sold out on vinyl . You might ask  why did I learn only yesterday that they had released  an album  especially when this one  was out one year  ago . The answer is because I am French and live in France .

I think *had* is not mandatory here as the sequence of events is clear, am I right?

Comment: Maybe not mandatory, but the sequence is not obvious. *Had released* adds clarity, and matches "learn only yesterday that we *had released* an album."

Comment: **had** is not mandatory; you could use simple past, correct. BTW, "You could say why did you..." would be better as "You might ask, why did I..."  Also, "and that it seems" is not something you learned, therefore: "... but it seems..."

Comment: 'LP' and 'French'.

Comment: You might want to work on the sentence beginning "You might ask why...". The use of *we* isn't right in that sentence, also the whole sentence is awkward and mostly redundant. Perhaps try something shorter: "You might ask why, considering it has been out for a year".

Comment: I suppose that I can  also to the past simple  for the  sentence beginning by you might ask